# LINQ query can I match object type property with another object in where condition

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have an object **`BankAccount`** which I want to check for match in LINQ query.

There is another object **`LenderAccount`** which has reference of **`BankAccount`** entity.

Finally an object **`LoanConnection`** has reference of **`LenderAccount`**. I am looking for all connections that have particular **`BankAccount`**.

Following is the code:

```
var bankAccount = accountService.GetBankAccountById(1);
var lenderCons = lenderConnectionService.List().Where(c => c.LenderAccount.BankAccount == bankAccount).ToList();
```

Above query seems to work. But I thought in LINQ we need to check in where condition with basic data types (like: integer, string, double etc) like following code.

```
var bankAccount = accountService.GetBankAccountById(1);
var lenderCons = lenderConnectionService.List().Where(c => c.LenderAccount.BankAccount.Id == bankAccount.Id).ToList();
```

Am I doing anything wrong here or is it allowed in LINQ to check object type property in where conditions with **`==`** operator?

Comment: it sometimes happen if you have different contexts at work. I'm not completely sure about why, and would love an answer here or a way to force a population of an "old" context maybe with a new one. but you're not getting the BackAccount whole populated within LenderAccount. but it has some of the values in this case ID, but so does LenderAccount.BankAccountForeignKeyID. Not 100% sure this is what's happening here, but I have had similar issues.

Comment: Ideally in your first case I would have expected that its comparing object references and hence should return true always while in the second case its comparing purely bankaccount ids and will return true only if the ids match..Can you let us know if by chance your IDs are same for all cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LINQ `where` statement just compare every object of the collection with your `bankAccount`. Yes, you can use any types you want in this statement.

But in your code, it compares **only links** to the objects. This is a default behavior for reference types.
I think, currently, references are to the same object and everything works fine. But creating objects in memory and links to them, it's a `CLR` work, and it may change from version to version.

So, I would recommend you to implement overridden comparison methods ([**MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) explanation and example) for your `BankAccount` type. You cannot know if objects reference to the same object in memory.

And, in the overridden comparison you will need manual check if `id`'s are equal or not. Then you can use usual object comparison (your first example) without guessing it will work or not.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was about to post. Anyways I think you need not override the comparison if you are explicitly checking for id only as in the second case. However, if you are using the first way than ofcourse it makes sense to override the comparison where you explicitly check for id.

Comment: I think, anyway, it would be better to compare **objects**, not **their properties**. The code would look _clearer_ and more logic.

Answer (score 0):

As you explained and what I understood is, you are trying to achieve all those connections having the same bank account. 
What you are trying to do in your first code that to compare bankAccount object using '==' operator.
from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx),

> For predefined value types, the equality operator (==) returns true if the values of its operands are equal, false otherwise. For reference types other than string, == returns true if its two operands refer to the same object. For the string type, == compares the values of the strings.

So, being more accurate, comparing their id's are more preferable. ie,

```
var bankAccount = accountService.GetBankAccountById(1);
var lenderCons = lenderConnectionService.List().Where(c => c.LenderAccount.BankAccount.Id == bankAccount.Id).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty unclear what you are doing in the *lenderConnectionService* but if you haven't executed the query against the database it will work. But if you already have executed the query and **turned off** *lazy loading* in EF then it will **not work**. It's always better to compare the *Ids*.

In your DbContext you can enable/disable *lazy loading*.

```
Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true/false;
```

With *lazy loading* turned off you can retrieve related entities with the function **Include**, reade more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx).